# Help with Coinbase? Confused BCC address with BTC one

Tags: transactions, address

As a newbie a friend who owed me some money suggested I get Coinbase and let him pay me in bitcoin.  I got the address but didn’t realize I got the address to my BCC wallet instead of bitcoin wallet.  It is quite a lot of money and I have no idea what to do.  Am i just out of luck?  Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: He did send it.  Here is the address.  1Pb8E4VMy2zfCJST3FJNUJ41J1Kn9YovpE.  Is there a way to see where the coin is?  It’s 8500 dollars.

Comment: You are at Coinbase's mercy. Coinbase has the funds now. Ask their support nicely if they can recover it for you, I'm sure a deal can be made.

Answer (score -1):

Did he actually send you the bitcoins to the BCC address? If yes, and the transaction has been sent to the blockchain, then you are indeed out of luck and can't recover that. 
Sorry!

Comment: Coinbase probably have that address, try contacting their support